# Searching for my comments with score 5 or more

Tags: support, search

I recently received the PUNDIT badge (Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.)  Is there a way I can use the PSE search facility to find these comments?

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101277/how-many-upvotes-have-i-received-on-my-comments/101279#comment792937_101279

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the link put forward by @ACB in a comment on the question suggests, you can use the **Stack Exchange Data Explorer** for this exact purpose. Specifically, if you navigate to [this previously created Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/238582/comments-and-votes) (here modified for use on Puzzling specifically), you can generate a list of all your comments within the Puzzling site arranged from highest score to lowest, with the PostID for easy reference if you need to navigate to the post on which you left a particular comment.

To use it, just enter your numeric user ID specific to Puzzling (obtainable from the URL in the address bar when you click on your own profile) in the space provided in the 'Enter Parameters' section, declare that you are not a robot, and run the query - voila!

(NB This query will run on any particular site in the network by adapting the word immediately following 'https://data.stackexchange.com/' in the link above...)